# Is HTTPS connectionless or connection-oriented?

Tags: https, tls

We all know that HTTP is connectionless. After a request-response, the connection is torn down. It remembers the "state" based on cookies supplied by the browser.

Is this the case with HTTPS also? Since it works over TLS/SSL, is the connection persistent? Will my system have an established connection to port 443 of the server for the entire duration when I am interacting with the website? If yes, then is it not too much of an overhead for the server to maintain a lot many connections at a time?

I was reading [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_overview.htm#:%7E:text=HTTP%20is%20connectionless%3A%20The%20HTTP,client%20waits%20for%20the%20response.&text=Further%20requests%20are%20made%20on,are%20new%20to%20each%20other) and was a bit confused by what it explains.

Answer (score 3):

> We all know that HTTP is connectionless

No, HTTP is *stateless*. It still runs on top of a connection-oriented transport (typically TCP), but it does not assign any state to that particular connection. The client is free to re-use the same connection for multiple requests (as many HTTP/1.1 clients do), or to create a brand new connection for each request (as HTTP/1.0 clients used to do).

(HTTP itself is neither connectionless nor connection-oriented, because maintaining connections the job of *transport* protocols. TCP, SCTP, QUIC are connection-oriented transports, while UDP is connectionless. Some application protocols associate state with the underlying connection; some carry all relevant state in their own packets.)

> Is this the case with HTTPS also? Since it works over TLS/SSL, is the connection persistent?

Both regular HTTP and TLS-based HTTPS still use the same transport (TCP), and both handle connections the same way. TLS is only an extra layer in-between HTTP and TCP.

> Will my system have an established connection to port 443 of the server for the entire duration when I am interacting with the website?

Most web browsers will reuse the same 1-2 connections to request all necessary resources, but will close them a few minutes after those connections become idle.

Comment: Well this makes sense. Tutorialspoint's description got me confused : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_overview.htm#:~:text=HTTP%20is%20connectionless%3A%20The%20HTTP,client%20waits%20for%20the%20response.&text=Further%20requests%20are%20made%20on,are%20new%20to%20each%20other.

So basically, being a connection-oriented/connection-less is not a property of an application layer protocol. 
What being stateless means, the server won't store the context of the data over the chunk of requests, that needs to be handled via cookies. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically right.

Answer (score 0):

http and https are connectionless in much the same way - they are, except when they arn't.  HTTPS just wraps some encryption around the stream.

Both can work 1 request per tcp connection and both can allow you persist connections.

Certainly https overhead is a concern, (and you are right that there is more back-and-forth for https  ) if you are doing volume, but I guess thats what reverse proxies are for.